# How to make a switch button/reverse button. Similar to Google translate

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm make a little calculator that convert KG in Pounds and Pounds in KG and write on an input. But, I want make this with only one button to calculate! Understand?

> KG to POUNDS -> KG * 2.2046
>
> POUNDS to KG -> POUNDS / 2.2046

**Example 1:**

> Field 1: 50 kg
>
> ....calc...
>
> Field 2 (result): 110.23 Pounds

Then there will be the button for me to change the function (Button of Google Translate to change the languages in every click) I click and ..

**Example 2:**

> Field 1: 100 pounds
>
> ...calc...
>
> Field 2 (result): 45.35

Can you understand what I do?

```
function calcPD(){
    
    var pound = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var calc = quilos / 2.2046;
    var resul = document.getElementById("pound").value=calcularr.toFixed(2);        
    }
                    
function calcKg(){      
    
    var kg = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var calc = quilo * 2.2046;
    var resul = document.getElementById("pound").value=calcular.toFixed(2);                         
    }
 funcion invert(){

      ???
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is just a simple variable to keep track of what "mode" you are in. I've built an example for you to see how this would work (I used bootstrap to make it pretty, but obviously that's optional):

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13851/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Input: 
            <input id="inputNum" class="form-control" type="number"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Output: 
            <input id="outputNum" class="form-control" type="text" disabled></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span id="modeText">lbs to kg</span>
    <button id="switch" class="btn pull-right">Switch</button> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//0 = lbs to kg, 1 = kg to lbs
var mode = 0;

var inputNum = $("#inputNum");
var outputNum = $("#outputNum");
var switchMode = $("#switch");
var modeText = $("#modeText");

var calculateKgs = function() {
    outputNum.val(inputNum.val()/2.2046);
};

var calculateLbs = function() {
    outputNum.val(inputNum.val()*2.2046);
};

var calculate = function() {
    if(mode == 0)
        calculateKgs();
    else
        calculateLbs();
};

inputNum.change(calculate);
inputNum.keyup(calculate);

switchMode.click(function() {
    if(mode) {
        mode = 0;
        modeText.text("lbs to kg");
    }
    else {
        mode = 1;
        modeText.text("kg to lbs");
    }

    calculate();
});
```

Comment: Hi user3495690! Was exactly that I was need!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuizSantos No problem, happy to help! Do you mind marking this as the correct answer? I'm trying to get my points up :P

Comment: All right. But, I'm have a little problem. When I try run the code in my computer, appears an error in Jquery. I cared all files JS of the bootstrap and nothing... I downloaded the JQuery compiled (2.1.4), I care to code and nothing too..  (The CSS of bootstrap is working). What should I do?

Comment: @LuizSantos I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *cared*, but did you remember to include jQuery in your HTML, as per these instructions: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: I use the google translate, sorry. I meant "Import/Add" the Jquery to code, but I'm can't.

Comment: @LuizSantos Did you try the link I posted? It's a tutorial on how to add jQuery to your webpage

Comment: I have had success, thank you so much! Was the order of the code. I changed and it is working now!

Comment: @LuizSantos Great! I hope your project turns out well!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use `innerHtml`. Some basic pseudo logic for you:

```
var a = document.getElementById("one").innerHtml;
var b = document.getElementById("two").innerHtml;

document.getElementById("one").innerHtml = b;
document.getElementById("two").innerHtml = a;
```